# Advantages to storing UserId instead of Username in sql audit columns such as CreatedBy/ModifiedBy

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have always wondered why in most examples/tutorials everyone stores the User's name in audit database columns such as `CreatedBy`/`ModifiedBy`.

In the back of my head I have always wondered, what if the system I am building will allow the user to change their username as long as it is not taken.

Wouldn't I want to store the user's Id in this case?

I really don't want this to be an opinion based question. So the kind of answer I expect is a situation when storing the user's name in audit columns is fine and a situation when storing the user's id in audit columns is fine.

Comment: Most people use UserName in `Modified By` fields to be the network user id for example if my user name were `John Fields` the would probably store it a `jfields` it's also a matter of  preference for sorting capabilities if the user id's were always numeric's then sorting on the field would be much quicker on a numeric field vs a varchar field.. its totally `Opinion Based / Departmental Preference`

Comment: There's no reason you cannot store both the `UserId` and `UserName` in the audit table; just be sure to disable any FK constraint on either field.

Comment: @MethodMan I like this approach, but it still isn't 100% reliable if the user can change their first and last name in the system. For example, if a woman gets married.

Comment: this is what you have HR department for and Peoplesoft or ActiveDirectory the only thing in that case is the `userid` in the system it should not change @BlakeRivell do you work for a company that has an IT department , Director or Lead Developer? I would ask what is the standard when coding / designing audit trials in your case

Comment: @BlakeRivell - Not just women, both man and woman can change their names when they get married, such as when they hyphenate their last names.

Comment: So when using Microsoft's built-in IdentityUser which contains Username and Email fields, but can be extended... Do most people just store the Username as their CreatedBy/ModifiedBy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no chance this isn't an opinion based question. However, consider what happens when you use the UserID. The next logical conclusion is to make a foreign key to the user table. Now you can't delete a user if they have an audit row.

Ok no biggie. Skip the foreign key and put in the UserID with no foreign key. Now how useful is the audit information if the User row is deleted? Especially if you have an identity or uniqueidentifier as your UserID. The value is now completely useless because to derive ANY value from it you have to join to your user table.

Now does it make sense why most of the time you see UserName instead of UserID?

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. I am disappointed that I wasn't able to think through that myself considering the experience I have. So what you are saying is that there is really no safe way to store this field and always have it be 100% reliable unless there are rules involved (such as User can never be deleted). I am assuming this is where Logging comes in so you can always see who did what through logging. Sorry if the question was opinion based, however I see your answer being helpful to many people.

Comment: You could possibly implement soft deletes on the user table and then it would be totally reliable. Of course that comes with its own challenges but might be a solution in some situations.

Comment: Now consider what happens when another user with the same name shows up. Did he do all those correct or malicious data modifications? Does he have permissions to all records created by prior user? I guess not. That's why you have to store all linked sensitive data or purge everything referencing removed row.

Comment: @IvanStarostin this is exactly why I stated this is going to be primarily opinion based. There are no right or wrong answers to this type of thing. What works in one environment may not work in another. And things like you describe may be critical in some systems where in other systems it doesn't matter that much. And even in some systems those are AD accounts which only become disabled so a duplicate isn't actually possible. As with everything SQL Server....it depends. :D